# How to get the latest block of a contract with web3.php?

Tags: web3js, php, web3.php

I need to get the latest block because 'latest' as toBlock doesn't work. I tried the code below with $toBlock = 'latest'

```
$this->eth->getLogs([
  'fromBlock' => (is_int($fromBlock)) ? '0x' . dechex($fromBlock) : $fromBlock,
  'toBlock' => (is_int($toBlock)) ? '0x' . dechex($toBlock) : $toBlock,
  'topics' => [$this->ethabi->encodeEventSignature($this->events[$eventName])],
  'address' => $this->toAddress
],<callback here>);
```

but it says: fromBlock must be less than or equal to toBlock. It only returns a result when I set fromBlock to 0 and toBlock to 'latest' or when I use 2 specific blocknumbers.

That's why I need to get the latest block.

** EDIT: This is the contract.php I'm using: https://github.com/Nanolucas/web3.php/blob/master/src/Contract.php

Thanks!

Comment: Does `$this->eth->eth_blockNumber()` help?

Comment: Nah, that'd give me the latest block of the chain, not the contract.

Comment: As I can see from your question, you needed the latest block. If not, please edit your question so proper help would be provided.

Comment: you're right. Just edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: I still am having trouble to get your Q. If you are trying to get the logs for an specific address in the last mined block (is this your question?), just remove 'fromBlock' & 'toBlock' keys/values. According to the [eth wiki](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getlogs) those fields are optional and their defaults are 'latest' (mined blocks). Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with you and I used to do that but it doesn't work anymore. When I remove both 'fromBlock' and 'toBlock', I get the following error: "fromBlock must be less than or equal to toBlock". So, since 'latest' doesn't work, I thought I could get around it and get the last block instead.